# CSS selector not working in JSP page embedded JavaScript to set div background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I'm trying to implement an image uploader which will allow users to upload pictures and set them as the background of a div (in this case .mm11 is a post-it style card which contains a 'choose file' and an 'upload file' button and starts off with no background image

I have worked out how to upload the pictures to a folder in my tomcat directory, and I can display them using

```
<img src='uploads/<%=fileName%>' />
```

but I'm struggling to set the picture as the background! Any advice would be much appreciated, have been struggling with this for hours..

```
<div id="uploadsContainer" class="mm11Container" style="top:100px; left: 100px;">
            <div id="g" class="mm11 card front face">
                <!--button id="uploadbutton" type="button">Upload Image11</button-->
                <form action="

                    <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>

                    <%
                    File file ;
                    String fileName = "";
                    int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
                    int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
                    ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
                    String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

                    // Verify the content type
                    String contentType = request.getContentType();
                    //if (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0) {

                    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                    // maximum size that will be stored in memory
                    factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
                    // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
                    factory.setRepository(new File("uploads/"));

                    // Create a new file upload handler
                    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                    upload.setHeaderEncoding("ISO-8858-2");

                    // maximum file size to be uploaded.
                    upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
                    try {
                    // Parse the request to get file items.
                    List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

                    // Process the uploaded file items
                    Iterator iter = fileItems.iterator();

                        while ( iter.hasNext () ) {
                        FileItem fi = (FileItem)iter.next();
                        if ( !fi.isFormField () ) {
                            // Get the uploaded file parameters
                            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                            fileName = fi.getName();
                            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
                            // Write the file
                            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
                            file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
                        }
                        else {
                            file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
                        }
                        fi.write( file ) ;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }

                %>"
                    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input class="uploads" type="file" name="file" size="50"/>
                    <input class="uploadFile" type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        /*$(this).parents().eq(2).css(&#39;background-size&#39;, &#39;100&#37;&#39;);$(this).parents().eq(2).empty().css(&#39;background-image&#39;, &#39;uploads/<%=fileName%>&#39;);*/

                        $('.mm11').css('background-image', 'uploads/<%=fileName%>');
                        alert("here filename = "+'uploads/<%=fileName%>');
                    </script>
                    <!--img src='uploads/<%=fileName%>' /-->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have also tried ajax by replacing the code in the script tags with

```
var ajx=new XMLHttpRequest();


ajx.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (ajx.readyState==4 &amp;&amp; ajx.status==200)
  {
     $("#g").css('background-image', 'uploads/<%=fileName%>');
  }
}
ajx.open("GET","index.jsp",true);
ajx.send();
```

But this doesn't work either..to test I was correctly accessing the div, I added this to the css line:

```
$("#g").empty().css('background-image', 'uploads/<%=fileName%>');
```

which does clear the div...so why isn't the background image being set??

Another possibly related problem is that if I don't include the line

```
if (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)
```

(currently commented out), the alert pops up anyway the first time I visit the page, and fileName is set to the last file I tried to upload. However, if I DO include it, I get a Null Pointer Exception as contentType is null...does anyone know what this is about?

Comment: _“so why isn't the background image being set??”_ – because that is simply not the _correct syntax_ to set a background-image …? (Go learn some CSS basics if you don’t know what is.)

Comment: please tell me how to do it in that case! I've used the exact same syntax before and it has worked!

Comment: No, that has most certainly not worked using the “exact same syntax” before. And as I said, if you don’t know what the correct syntax for specifying a background-image via CSS is … go look it up!

Comment: changing it to this works in this case:

$("#g").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/<%=fileName%>)');

but the remaining problem is that when I first load the page, it instantly clears the div and sets the background to the last fileName...how do I stop this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
background-image', 'uploads/<%=fileName%>'
```

Correct code:

```
background-image:url("uploads/<%=fileName%");
```

slightly different.

Hope it helps.